# How do I enable custom attributes? (can assign on class, but not displaying for transaction)

Tags: acumatica

I defined several new screens in Acumatica 2018R2 and need to enable attribute support according the class assigned to the transaction.  The class screen appears to allow attaching attributes, but the transactional screen does not display any attribute.  I found several examples on Stack Overflow, but the only clue I see seems to be that if the class id cannot be determined then no attributes will show.  However, upon debug, I see that the class id is found.

This is my test code where I have tried stripping down to a very basic test.

AAClass

```
using PX.Data;
using System;

namespace Attributes
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AAClass : IBqlTable
    {
        #region ClassID
        [PXDBIdentity]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class ID")]
        public virtual int? ClassID { get; set; }
        public abstract class classID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region ClassCD
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Class CD")]
        public virtual string ClassCD { get; set; }
        public abstract class classCD : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region Descr
        [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Descr")]
        public virtual string Descr { get; set; }
        public abstract class descr : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByID
        [PXDBCreatedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByScreenID
        [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByScreenID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedDateTime
        [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = SSCS.IN.Messages.FldCreatedDateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByScreenID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedDateTime
        [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = SSCS.IN.Messages.FldLastModifiedDateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region Tstamp
        [PXDBTimestamp()]
        public virtual byte[] Tstamp { get; set; }
        public abstract class tstamp : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region NoteID
        [PXNote]
        public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
        public abstract class noteID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

AAClassMaint

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;

namespace Attributes
{
    public class AAClassMaint : PXGraph<AAClassMaint, AAClass>
    {

        #region Data Views
        [PXViewName("Classes")]
        public PXSelect<AAClass> Classes;

        [PXViewName("Attributes")]
        public CSAttributeGroupList<AAClass, AATag> Mapping;
        #endregion

    }
}
```

AATag

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using System;

namespace Attributes
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AATag : IBqlTable
    {
        #region TagID
        [PXDBIdentity]
        public virtual int? TagID { get; set; }
        public abstract class tagID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region TagCD
        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tag ID")]
        public virtual string TagCD { get; set; }
        public abstract class tagCD : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region MyClassID
        [PXDBInt()]
        [PXSelector(
            typeof(AAClass.classID),
            typeof(AAClass.classCD),
            typeof(AAClass.descr),
            SubstituteKey = typeof(AAClass.classCD)
        )]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Class ID")]
        public virtual int? MyClassID { get; set; }
        public abstract class myClassID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByID
        [PXDBCreatedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedByScreenID
        [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdByScreenID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region CreatedDateTime
        [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = SSCS.IN.Messages.FldCreatedDateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
        public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedByScreenID
        [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
        public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region LastModifiedDateTime
        [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = SSCS.IN.Messages.FldLastModifiedDateTime)]
        public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
        public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region Tstamp
        [PXDBTimestamp()]
        public virtual byte[] Tstamp { get; set; }
        public abstract class tstamp : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region NoteID
        [PXNote]
        public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
        public abstract class noteID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion

        #region Attributes
        public abstract class attributes : IBqlField { }
        [CRAttributesField(typeof(AATag.myClassID))]
        public virtual string[] Attributes { get; set; }
        public virtual int? ClassID
        {
            get { return MyClassID; }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

AATagEntry

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CR;

namespace Attributes
{
    public class AATagEntry : PXGraph<AATagEntry, AATag>
    {
        #region Data Views
        [PXViewName("Classes")]
        public PXSelect<AATag> Tags;

        [PXViewName("Answers")]
        public CRAttributeList<AATag> Answers;
        #endregion
    }
}
```

As I understand the various posts for this topic, the key requirements are:

- Define MAPPING in the class maintenance screen

  ```
  [PXViewName("Attributes")]
  public CSAttributeGroupList<AAClass, AATag> Mapping;
  ```
- Define ANSWERS in the transactional entry screen

  ```
  [PXViewName("Answers")]
  public CRAttributeList<AATag> Answers;
  ```
- Include NoteID in the transactional table
- Add ATTRIBUTES to the transactional table, including a field for ClassID

  ```
  public abstract class attributes : IBqlField { }
  [CRAttributesField(typeof(AATag.myClassID))]
  public virtual string[] Attributes { get; set; }
  public virtual int? ClassID
  {
      get { return MyClassID; }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As HB_Acumatica suggested in the comments, the issue appeared to be with the ClassID fields being defined as integer.

I removed the original ClassID (int) fields and renamed the ClassCD (string) fields in the Class DAC's. Next, I changed the ClassID fields in the transactional DAC's to strings.  Problem solved.  The attribute tab on the transactional entry screens now display the attributes assigned to the class selected.

Lesson learned:  A "Class" DAC should not have a ClassID/ClassCD pair, but rather a simple string ClassID field.  (Typically named specific to the type of class, i.e. TagClassID)  The Class ID used in the transactional tables will then use the string Class ID.

Answer (score 1):

`CRAttributesField` attribute will build a request with the generic type (classIdField) provided in it's parameter. In your case that would be `AATag.myClassID` :

```
protected static Type GetAttributesSearchCommand(Type classIdField)
{
    var cmd = BqlCommand.Compose(typeof (Search2<,,>), typeof (CSAttribute.attributeID),
        typeof (InnerJoin<,>), typeof (CSAttributeGroup),
        typeof (On<,>), typeof (CSAttributeGroup.attributeID), typeof (Equal<>),
        typeof (CSAttribute.attributeID),
        typeof(Where<,,>), typeof(CSAttributeGroup.entityType), typeof(Equal<>), typeof(Required<>), typeof(CSAttributeGroup.entityType),
        typeof (And<,>), typeof (CSAttributeGroup.entityClassID), typeof (Equal<>), typeof (Current<>),
        classIdField);
    return cmd;
}
```

So the key part of the request where clause will be:

```
And<CSAttributeGroup.entityClassID, Equal<Current<AATag.myClassID>>>
```

This means you must have a current AATag record in memory:

```
Caches[typeof(AATag)].Current
```

I suggest you first trace the value (Help->Trace window) to validate it's non null:

```
public void AATag_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row is AATag)
   {
      PXTrace.WriteInformation(((AATag)e.Row).myClassID);
   }
}
```

If it is null, you will have to join AATag in the relevant DataView (preferred) or set it explicitely in some events.
Using Acumatica Request Profiler (SM205070
) can also help to determine why the request is not returning any record.

Comment: AATag is the primary DAC of the graph, and I'm viewing the record on the screen.  However, the attribute section does not fill in.  My class ID is an int and displayed back with PXSelector providing a substitute key on classCD.  The trace returns a class ID of "1".  Interestingly enough, CSAttributeGroup shows an EntityClassID of "AAA" (my classCD value) instead of "1" (my classID value).

Comment: What is not filling? Can you see the attribute columns? Can you see the attribute values?

Comment: The class screen allows me to assign attributes to the class.  However on the entry screen for "AATag", the attribute grid is empty - none of the attributes assigned to the selected class ID are displaying. http://prntscr.com/n9qgr7

Comment: ok the part not filling is not at all where I thought it was. That would be related to CRAttributeList instead of CRAttributesField.

Comment: Most obvious thing to check is if you have CommitChanges=True on the header fields.

Comment: ClassID in the context of Attributes is always of [PXDBString(10, IsUnicode = true)] type so yes you likely have a type mismatch there, I would have expected some runtime error though with an int there.

Comment: I copied the int? version from inventoryitem.cs where ClassID returns ItemClassID.  I did not have commitchanges = true on the class id, but setting that did not fix the issue.  I need to try to return the AAClass.ClassCD value to CRAttributeList, if I follow what you are suggesting.

Comment: The pattern in InventoryItem.cs is weird and complicated, not the best example to follow. It uses 'ParentItemClassID' field, redefines it in the graph to add INParentItemClass attribute where additional shenanigans affect ItemClassID. I have a hard time to follow it without debugger attached.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that since almost all examples have [CRAttributesField(typeof(string_type))] instead [CRAttributesField(typeof(int_type))] you will have an easier time implementing that. Those who use int type appear to have a lot of redefining and overriding logic that is hard to extract.

Comment: Some DAC who use string type on CRAttributesField are Vendor, Customer, Contact, BAccount.

Comment: I tried setting up a PXString with PXFormula to populate the classCD for use with the attribute.  No change.  I hardcoded for AATag.ClassID to return "BBB", but no change.  I will continue to run traces and debug and also check out the other examples you provided.

Comment: Running the request profiler (SM205070) would help. Any request that returns zero CSAnswers would be the culprit and a good place to start.