# How to display default values in grid view

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I would like to display default values in a grid view in the acumatica base screen "CR306000" ex:attributes tab

[image]

What code would I need to write to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer 1 (Attributes)**

The screen you showed in your question is a very special feature of Acumatica called Attributes.  An attribute is assigned to "Classes" such as Item Class for Inventory Items.  To add additional attributes in a screen, you first define the attribute on the Attributes screen (CS2050000) and then add it to each Class of the object where you want it to be used.  In the case of your screenshot, this would be Case Classes (CS206000).  Once you define a class, you can go to the Attributes tab to add the attributes that you defined that would be relevant for this class.  (For example, an Item Class for a pump might include horsepower as an attribute, but and Item Class for office supplies would not.)

Adding the the ability to use attributes to a custom screen requires:

1. Establishing a Custom Class DAC that your custom master (header) record will use,
2. Adding a ClassID field to your master DAC to store that Class, and
3. Defining the View, Tab, and Grid, to edit the attribute values.

Here is a link to the question where I learned to do this.  Code sample included, and the fix to my issue is noted.  [How do I enable custom attributes? (can assign on class, but not displaying for transaction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599118/how-do-i-enable-custom-attributes-can-assign-on-class-but-not-displaying-for)

**Answer 2 (Master-Detail with Default Details)**

If you are new to Acumatica development, you should start by completing the free training courses they provide.  These can be found at https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/ on the Acumatica website.  The specific course you want to review for this case is T210 Customized Forms and Master-Detail Relationships.  In section 4.2 on page 99 of the current training material, you will find a section that shows an example of prepopulating a "Default Warranty" when a new service-device pair of records is created.  The records and all custom created within the training course and would serve only as an example.

Effectively, you must do 2 things for the example in the training guide.  First, you create a "default record".  In the training guide, you define a Warranty record that will be associated to your service-device record by default.  Next, you create an event handler to actually populate the grid in the detail tab when the parent in the header is created.  The training guide shows how to do all this, but to the point... Use the RowInserted event to create the detail record.  The example from the training guide is as follows:

```
//Insert the default detail record.
protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<RSSVRepairPrice> e)
{
    if (Warranty.Select().Count == 0)
    {
        bool oldDirty = Warranty.Cache.IsDirty;

        // Retrieve the default warranty.
        Contract defaultWarranty = (Contract)DefaultWarranty.Select();
        if (defaultWarranty != null)
        {
            RSSVWarranty line = new RSSVWarranty();
            line.ContractID = defaultWarranty.ContractID;

            // Insert the data record into
            // the cache of the Warranty data view.
            Warranty.Insert(line);

            // Clear the flag that indicates in the UI whether the cache
            // contains changes.
            Warranty.Cache.IsDirty = oldDirty;
        }
    }
}
```

The key part of that is that you define the record (*RSSVWarranty line = ...*) and then insert it into the view associated to the grid (*Warranty.Insert(line);*)  The rest of the example is leveraging a special view to get the default warranty record from the warranty master table (Contract).

Comment: Hi Stevens, thank you for your valuable time to spend on this issue, this is good solution for me, I learned & tried  this code as per my requirement.  It is working fine

(when you post a question on Stack Overflow, please note that you will get much better responses if you explain more detail) --- Definitely I will follow this line .


One second tq for giving some valuable info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225310/how-to-show-images-inside-selector-lookupnot-working-properly

Hi Stevens, can you help me on this how to solve this issue , I tried to show the image in the lookup selector but it is not working properly. Can you help me on this where I did the mistake.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with that technique, but it sure sounds interesting.  I hope someone posts a good solution.